# Scala generic query predicate generation DSL (possibly similar to AlaSQL in javascript)?

Tags: scala, rest, dsl

I'm building a generic API that provides access to a ton of different data sets, and I would like to avoid creating specific query API's for each data type. I.e. for the Users endpoint needing to manually implement `name="Joe"`. I would rather the user be able to use some query language, like an SQL where predicate or something similar, to filter down these data sets. The set of data is ever growing, and we need a generic way to form query predicates.

Back when I was working with javascript, I used https://github.com/agershun/alasql to do simple predicates over objects in memory.

I'm looking for something similar in scala. It doesn't need to be SQL, it could be JSON or some other DSL.

I've looked at Calcite, and was able to get it to do WHERE predicates on data, but it took *a lot* of hacking. The Calcite library is incredibly large and complex. It requires a lot of objects to be instantiated to even generate one query. I don't want to pull that kind of heavy dependency into the project.

Comment: If you are familiar and happy with alasql, wouldn't it make sense to just use that? You can maybe try find a way to interace it with scala.js

Comment: Speed is somewhat of an issue in this application. We're trying to run this predicate on a potentially very large stream of data.